# How does the 'in' operator affect time complexity?

Tags: python-3.x

I've been coding in Python for 8 months or so and starting to get curious about how things work under the hood. One of the things I am curious about is how 'in' works.

Here is an example:

```
arr = [i for i in range(0,6,2)]

for j in range(0,7):
    if j in arr:
        print(j)
```

How does the 'in' operator search the arr for the number i? Does it do it linearly every time, i.e start from arr[0] every time and search for the number?

Comment: https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity

Comment: in time complexity will depend on the object your checking again. For a normal list it will be O(n) but if `arr` was just `range(0,6,2)` then `if j in arr:` would be complexity O(1). so the time compexity of in depends on the object your checking against

Comment: In case this leads to a followup question of 'how can I speed this up then?', convert `arr` into a set (or create a set `arr2` from it), then search in _that_ instead. One linear pass to create the set, then constant-time `in` checks, as opposed to linear-time `in` checks in every iteration of the `j` loop.